# c++ connect to mysql/mariadb is very slow

Tags: c++, mysql, mariadb

I write some c++ https server which get connection - make query to base and send answer. If I try send GET query for index.html endpoint I get real good result:

[image]

but if I send POST and connect to mysql, Requests/sec is very small:

[image]

I try different connectors: mysql, mariadb++, mariadbcpp (in code example) etc the result is the same.

Code example:

```
nlohmann::json PostResult = {};
const char *uri = "tcp://192.168.1.130:3306/test";
const char *user = "root";
const char *passwd = "123";

MariaCpp::scoped_library_init maria_lib_init;

try {
  MariaCpp::Connection conn;
  conn.connect(MariaCpp::Uri(uri), user, passwd);

  std::auto_ptr<MariaCpp::PreparedStatement> stmt(conn.prepare("SELECT a.id, a.msg_id, a.NUMBER, a.sign FROM chiffa a WHERE a.id =1"));
  stmt->execute();

  while (stmt->fetch()) {
    PostResult["id"] = stmt->getInt(0);
    PostResult["msg_id"] = stmt->getString(1);
    PostResult["NUMBER"] = stmt->getString(2);
    PostResult["msg_id"] = stmt->getString(3);  
  }
  conn.close();
}
catch (MariaCpp::Exception &e) {
  std::cerr << e << std::endl;   
}
```

Maybe anyone can help, how to increase Requests/sec? Thanks!

Comment: Step 1) make sure you are testing an optimised build, not a debug build.

Comment: it's optimised build. I try create keep mysql connection i full time, the result has become better - Requests/sec:    475.08, but it not a real that mast be

Comment: After 24 hours of UPTIME, from MySQL root login, please post TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%thread%'; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%'; and C) SELECT @@version;  Thanks  Welcome to stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

200 connections and queries per second isn't *that* bad for a naive implementation, particularly when the database is being hosted across another network boundary.

I'm certainly not surprised that it's 50 times faster than something that just returns some HTML.

Your server/application should maintain *one* connection (or a pool of connections), that it keeps alive all the time, and use that when a request is made, rather than constructing a fresh connection for each request.